# using tcpdf to export current php file

Tags: php, printing

i have a huge table in my php page that contains alot of php coding inside it
i want to export it using tcpdf

the example in samples of thier website prints html as a variable and export it like that

```
$tbl = <<<EOD
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="3">COL 1 - ROW 1<br />COLSPAN 3</td>
        <td>COL 2 - ROW 1</td>
        <td>COL 3 - ROW 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">COL 2 - ROW 2 - COLSPAN 2<br />text line<br />text line<br />text line<br />text line</td>
        <td>COL 3 - ROW 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>COL 3 - ROW 3</td>
    </tr>

</table>
EOD;
```

my table has many many sql and php coding ,,,,etc
any php code i put inside it not appeared on output
how to print it?

and here is my table i want to print

```
 <table class="table" width="95%">
          <tbody>
          <tr >
            <td width="20" class="tabletop">م</td>
            <td class="tabletop" >name</td>
            <td class="tabletop" style="width:120px">date</td>
            <td class="tabletop" style="width:120px">note1</td>

             <td class="tabletop" style="width:100px">note2</td>
             <td class="tabletop" style="width:90px">note3</td>

          </tr>
          <? $res=mysql_query($sql);
                 while($resArr=mysql_fetch_array($res)){ ?>

          <tr style="width:700px">
            <td  class="tabletext"><?= ++$serial;?></td>
            <td class="tabletext" ><?= $resArr[stName];?></td>
             <td class="tabletext"><?= $resArr['date'];?></td>
            <td class="tabletext" ><?= $resArr[matName];?></td>

            <td class="tabletext" ><? if($resArr[exam]==1) echo "work";else echo "final";?></td>
             <td class="tabletext" ><? if($resArr[exam_type]==1) echo "prac";else echo "test";?></td>

          </tr>

          <? }?>
          </tbody>
       </table>
```

Comment: don't echo anything write it all to a single variable which you then use as above

Comment: im sorry cant understand could you please give me code ofwhat you mean

Comment: update your question with a small sample of your code then i'll show what i mean in an answer

Comment: i update my question with the table i want to print

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php


$print = '<table class="table" width="95%">
          <tbody>
          <tr >
            <td width="20" class="tabletop">م</td>
            <td class="tabletop" >name</td>
            <td class="tabletop" style="width:120px">date</td>
            <td class="tabletop" style="width:120px">note1</td>
             <td class="tabletop" style="width:100px">note2</td>
             <td class="tabletop" style="width:90px">note3</td>
          </tr>';

$res = mysql_query($sql);
while ( $resArr = mysql_fetch_array($res) ){
    $print .= '
          <tr style="width:700px">
            <td  class="tabletext">'.$serial.'</td>
            <td class="tabletext" >'.$resArr['stName'].'></td>
             <td class="tabletext">'.$resArr['date'].'></td>
            <td class="tabletext" >'.$resArr['matName'].'></td>
<td class="tabletext">';

    if($resArr['exam']==1){
        $print .= 'work';
    }else{
        $print .= 'final';
    }

    $print .= '</td><td class="tabletext" >';

    if($resArr['exam_type']==1){
        $print .= "prac";
    }else{
        $print .= "test";
    }

    $print .= '</td></tr>';
}

$print .= '</tbody></table>';
```

then simply use the variable $print

Comment: is there is any other way to print the table without breaking it like that because i have on other pages huge huge tables